# Getting vertical lists of lists of lists in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

a List of Lists like

> Lists=[ [1,2,3],
>           [4,5,6],
>           [7,8,3] ]

and i want to get in this case all vertical lists like

> [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,3]

how to do that? i thought about 2 counters witch work together like two "for to do" repeats.
i need to check with "is_set" if [1,4,7] is a set or [3,6,3] witch of course is not.

like this:

> > el_at(Llist,Gl,1),
> >
> > > ```
> > > el_at(EList, Llist,1),
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >          globalListVertikalCheck(ListVertikal),
> > > >          addlist(Elist,ListVertikal,NewListVertikal),
> > > > ```
> >
> > el_at(Llist,Gl,2),
> >
> > > ```
> > > el_at(EList, Llist,2),
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >        globalListVertikalCheck(ListVertikal),
> > > >        addlist(Elist,ListVertikal,NewListVertikal),
> > > > ```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

A list of all vertical lists is known as a transposed matrix.
[SWI's library(clpfd)](http://prolog.cs.vu.nl/git/pl-devel.git/blob/HEAD:/library/clp/clpfd.pl#l5646) contains such code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the solution you propose, but I have another one. I will try to describe how it works and maybe than you can see what was wrong with your solution and why it didn't work.

Let's consider an example of [[1,2], [3,4]]. The idea is to go through the first sub-list [1,2] and create an incomplete result [[1],[2]], then go through the next one [3,4] and prepend (which is easier than append in Prolog) each item in it to the each sub-list in the result. We will end up with [[3,1], [4,1]]. The sub-lists are then reversed and we have the result [[1,3],[1,4]].

Now the implementation:
The `vertical` predicate is the core, it goes through the list of lists and the result is step by step accumulated in the Acc varible.

For each of the sublists, the `vertical` predicate calls the `addfirst` predicate, which takes each element of that sublist and prepends it to the list in which the previous results were accumulated.

```
vertical([X|Xs],Result):-
    createempty(X, Acc),
    vertical([X|Xs], Acc, ReversedResults),
    reverseall(ReversedResults, Result).

reverseall([], []).
reverseall([X|Xs], [XReversed|Rest]):-
    reverse(X, XReversed),
    reverseall(Xs, Rest).

createempty([], []).
createempty([X|Xs], [[]|R]):-createempty(Xs,R).

vertical([], Result, Result).
vertical([X|Xs], Acc, Result):-
    addfirst(X, Acc2, Acc),
    vertical(Xs, Acc2, Result).

addfirst([], [], []).   
addfirst(
    [Y|Ys], 
    [[Y|YVerticalRest]|ResultRest], 
    [YVerticalRest|VerticalsRest]):-
    addfirst(Ys, ResultRest, VerticalsRest).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a small implementation of transpose:
It works by taking the first element of every sublist. When it finishes, it recursively does the same but now with the next item of each list, and so on.

```
transpose(M, T):-
  transpose(M, [], T).

transpose([], [], []).
transpose([], S, [[]|T]):-
  S \= [] ->
   (reverse(S, M), transpose(M, [], T)).
transpose([[]|MTail], S, T):-
  transpose(MTail, S, T).
transpose([[Item|Tail]|MTail], S, [[Item|NTail]|T]):-
  transpose(MTail, [Tail|S], [NTail|T]).
```

Answer (score -1):

```
transpose([[]|_],[]) :- !.
transpose(L,[L1|R2]) :-
        transpose(L,L2,L1),
        transpose(L2,R2).

transpose([],[],[]) :- !.
transpose([[A|R1]|R2],[R1|R3],[A|R4]) :-
        transpose(R2,R3,R4).
```